Possible refutation of Cantor's Diagonal Argument for infinite binary sequences
Ok sorry if this is a newbie question but I'm going over Cantor's Diagonal Argument proving the uncountability of infinite binary strings.  I get that the diagonal trick means there will always be a binary string that is not within the enumerated subset and therefore no bijection of natural numbers and infinite binary strings, but then I get confused by the fact that binary strings can be used to represent natural numbers by converting to integers.  For example, let's say I start with binary string 0 and take it to correspond with 1 of natural numbers, then proceed from there constructing all binary strings, then I have
f(1) -> 0
f(2) -> 1
f(3) -> 10
f(4) -> 11
....and so on

Would this not be a bijection as it enumerates all possible binary strings as well as natural numbers with a one-to-one correspondence?
I know I must be missing something but it seems to work?
EDIT:
I just realized that the strings 00 and 01 would not be included in this enumeration which I think is the Cantor Argument.  Whoops!

Argument proving the uncountability of infinite binary strings --- Your enumeration is only an enumeration for FINITE-LENGTH binary strings. For example, there is no positive integer $n$ such that $f(n)$ is equal to $10101010 \ldots$ (the infinite binary string that begins with, and then repeats from that point on, the two-digits $1$ and $0$ in this order). Thus, while there are countably many finite-length binary strings, there are uncountably many finite- or infinite-length binary strings, and hence "almost all" of the latter consist of infinite-length binary strings.

Thank you kindly ser

This is almost certainly a duplicate of several existing questions on this site, by the way. I was near the comment character-max in my last comment, or I would have mentioned this and/or cited some. Look through those under "Related" to the right of your question.

Cantor's diagonal argument is correct and rigorous , but in fact hard to grasp. The "diagonal" is infinite long , so that this procedure to list infinite elements (moreover infinite long) is of course only a thought process. That makes it so difficult to understand it . Of course, this only applies to INFINITE binary sequences , the FINITE (but arbitary long) binary sequences form a countable set.
